# Remove all composite numbers from an array

Tags: arrays, math, numbers, theory, primes

I have a sorted array `a` having size 2*10<sup>5</sup> and 1≤A[i]≤10<sup>10</sup> containing both prime and composite numbers.  The numbers are generated as indicated below:

```
a[1] = 1
for i > 1
    a[i] = a[i-1]+(i/2)
```

How can I efficiently remove the composite numbers from the array?  One solution is to check the primality of each element with Rabin-Miller.  Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Is that supposed to be a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i/2]?

Comment: @stark no a[i]=a[i-1]+(i/2)

Comment: Only use Rabin-Miller if you have to.  Some of the numbers in a[] are fractions, such as a[3] = 3.5.  Fractions can never be prime.  There is a pattern to where the fractions appear in a[].  With the integers in a[] use simple factorisation to remove multiples of low primes: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 etc.  Onlt use R-M for the more difficult large integers.

Comment: As rossum says, you can immediately exclude any fractional values in your data set. (`if ((int)a[i] == a[i]) // a[i] is integer`) As far as speed goes, when it comes to large numbers, you're either going to be slow, or you're going to be guessing at the primality check (with some degree of accuracy depending on the test you use). While heuristic primality checks can certainly be fast, none are 100% accurate.

Comment: @rossum That's true if he's using floating point division... he might be using integer division, in which case i/2 is always an integer.

Comment: @chandan111, what exactly do you mean by removing the non-prime elements from the array?  Do you just want to flag each composite or do you want a new array created which does not contain any composites (if you do this, you will loose the recurrence relation you defined)?

Comment: @andand only flags not sepaate array needed and (i/2) is integer divison .

Comment: @chandan111 And are you using integer or floating point division?

Comment: @andand integer divison ofcourse.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your recurrence relation has a closed form expression of of:

```
a[i] = floor([i/2]^2) + 1
```

The class of primes you are looking for in this array are therefore [near-square primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Near-SquarePrime.html) and [resources exist](http://oeis.org/A002496) for prividing some additional information when `i` is an even number.  If that was the extent of it, that would probably suffice.

But, that's not it.  When `i` is odd, it's a bit more difficult.  I couldn't find a solution for this case, and am forced to conclude your best approach to finding a general solution is a sufficiently large [Sieve of Erasthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_eratosthenes) as the basis for checking the primality of `a[i]` for all `i`.  Since `a[20000]` = (1e8)+1, a properly implemented sieve will require about 1.25e7 bytes (about 13MB) of memory.  While large it's still manageable on most modern computers.  Of course if this is for an embedded system...